# Error trying to save data in django via ajax(fetch)

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-models

I have a model that references other models, I am trying to save data using ajax

Example:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Main(models.Model):
    name = ....
    friend = models.ForeignKey(Friend, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

All body comes from ajax(fetch) request

I have a table (html), and add data to cells, then with the
enter event, send data.

Like this:

```
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  //in this scenario I already have the whole row
  // get full_row `row_data`
  post_ajax = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-CSRFToken": crf_token, // I get it with a regular expression
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(row_data),
  };

  fetch("my_url", post_ajax)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error))
    .then((response) => console.log("Success:", response));
});
```

My view function

```
def save_post(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        data = json.loads(body_unicode)      
        print('here the data arrives',data)
        # here the data arrives {'name': 'Ale', 'friend_id': 22}
        Main.objects.create(name=data['name'], friends=data['friend_id'])

        return JsonResponse({"instance": data}, status=200)

    return JsonResponse({"error": ""}, status=400)
```

This is the error

```
raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" %
                (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Main() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Friends'
```

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Please provide the template code you are using to send the AJAX request to Django view

Comment: @MichaelHawkins I update my question

Comment: What does the JSON data look like that is coming across when you print it?

Comment: @MichaelHawkins like this `{'name': 'Ale', 'friend_id': 22...}` is js and python json.loads

Comment: I edited my answer below - see if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

When you are creating the `Main` object, try making the "`friend`" attribute an object, like this:

```
friend = Friend.objects.get(id=data['friend_id'])
Main.objects.create(name=data['name'], friend=friend)
```

Also, the main issue appears to be you are calling the column "**friends**" but it should be "**friend**" when you are creating the `Main` object.

This:

```
 Main.objects.create(name=data['name'], friends=data['friend_id'])
```

Should be:

```
 Main.objects.create(name=data['name'], friend=data['friend_id'])
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

Assuming you are using JQuery in the template to send an AJAX request, since you did not specify.

In your urls.py:

```
...
path('/api/post_friend/', post_friend_api, name="post_friend_api"),
...
```

In your template :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#myBurron").click(function(){
            var csrfToken = $( "input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']"); // assuming this is a form
            var friend_name = $("#friend_name").val();
                $.ajax({ url: '{% url 'post_friend_api' %}',
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: {'friend':friend_name, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrfToken.val()},
                                    cache: false
                           }).done(function(data) {
                                if (data.result === true){
                                    alert(data.message);
                               }
                           });
                      });
                  });
            </script>
```

In your views.py:

```
        from django.http import JsonResponse

        def post_friend_api(request):
              data = {}
              if request.POST.get('friend', None) is not None:
                  friend_name = request.POST.get('post_note')
                  # save the object and indicate success
                  data['result'] = True
                  data['message'] = "Friend saved successfully"
                  ...
              if request.is_ajax():
                 return JsonResponse(data)
              else:
                 return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

When you are sending data via POST don't forget to pass along your CSRF token as in the example above. This assumes you have a form on the page you can get it from, otherwise you can use something like this to get it:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

If you don't want to deal with the CSRF token, you can mark the view with the `@csrf_exempt` decorator and remove the '`csrfmiddlewaretoken`' data element from the Ajax call in the template, but it may not be ideal or the most secure. An example of that:

```
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    from django.http import JsonResponse

    @csrf_exempt()
    def post_note_api(request):
           ...
```

If you post more details I can update my answer.